# Testing if a hash has any of a number of keys

Tags: ruby, hash

I was wondering if there was a better way to test if a hash has any keys from an array. I want to use it something like this:

```
keys = %w[k1 k2 k5 k6]
none = true if hash.key?(keys)
```

Or am I going to have to loop this?

Comment: I don't see, why this question shoud have `rails` tag.

Comment: I don't see why you need to be the fun police.

Answer (score 83, accepted):

No need to loop:

```
(hash.keys & keys).any? # => true
```

Explanation:

`.keys` returns all keys in a hash as an array. `&` intersects two arrays, returning any objects that exists in both arrays. Finally, `.any?` checks if the array intersect has any values.

Comment: Well...no looping yourself, but behind-the-scenes overkill for testing. It's still an elegant answer, but not necessarily the absolute-most-performant.

Answer (score 9):

```
keys.any? { |i| hash.has_key? i }
```