# Determine if hash contains any key from a set of keys?

Tags: ruby, hash

Do you know a pretty ruby way to find if an hash has one of some keys ?

```
h = {:a => 1, :c => 3, :d => 4}
# keys to find are :a, :b or :e
```

I know that I can do a :

```
h.key?(:a) || h.key?(:b) || h.key?(:e)
```

But I was wondering if there was a prettier way to do it ! :)

Thanks a lot !

Comment: Checkout this awesome answer which does not use any loops: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4743729/238880

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Consider [`Enumerable.any?`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Enumerable.html#M001500)

```
[:a, :b, :e].any? {|k| h.key?(k)}
```

From IRB:

```
>> h = {:a => 1}; [:x].any? {|k| h.key?(k)}                    
=> false                                                                
>> h = {:a => 1}; [:x, :a].any? {|k| h.key?(k)}                
=> true
```

Happy coding.

Comment: And of course use `.all?` if you want to see if it has ALL the keys specified :).

Comment: Love this code - thanks!

Answer (score 13):

Here is how you get all of the matching keys from an array:

```
> {:a => 1, :c => 3, :d => 4}.keys & [:a, :d, :e]
 => [:a, :d]
```

and if you want a boolean (following Andrew's suggestion):

```
> ({:a => 1, :c => 3, :d => 4}.keys & [:a, :d, :e]).empty?
 => false 
> ({:a => 1, :c => 3, :d => 4}.keys & [:f, :e]).empty?
 => true
```

Comment: +1 Nice "alternative" solution with a set intersection. I would add that length > 0 of the result implied existence of at least one key.

Comment: @pst: You could use `.empty?` if you just wanted a boolean.

Comment: Or `.any?` to check the opposite.

Comment: .keys converts symbolic keys into strings, so it should be check like - {:a => 1, :c => 3, :d => 4}.keys & ['a', 'd', 'e'].

Answer (score 3):

I would do something like this:

```
[:a, :b, :e].any?{ |val| h.key?(val) }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
h.select{|k| [:b, :w, :e].include?(k) }.empty?
h.select{|k| [:a, :w, :e].include?(k) }.empty?
```

And you get hash (key and value) of matching key in return (without empty?)

Comment: +1 For a different answer. However, this turns the operation into `O(k*n)`, where `k` is the number of the keys in the hash and `n` is the length of the sequence with keys to try and find.