# Check if a hash's keys include all of a set of keys

Tags: ruby

I'm looking for a better way to do

```
if hash.key? :a &&
   hash.key? :b &&
   hash.key? :c &&
   hash.key? :d
```

preferably something like

```
hash.includes_keys? [ :a, :b, :c, :d ]
```

I came up with

```
hash.keys & [:a, :b, :c, :d] == [:a, :b, :c, :d]
```

but I dont like having to add the array twice though

Comment: Awesome answer here which does not use any loops: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4743729/238880

Comment: @PratikKhadloya - I'm not sure that applies here: this is about ensuring _all_ keys are present rather than any.

Answer (score 123, accepted):

```
%i[a b c d].all? {|s| hash.key? s}
```

Comment: If you want to make it more complicated, you could use `[:a, :b, :c, :d].all?(&hash.method(:key?))`.

Answer (score 21):

@Mori's way is best, but here's another way:

```
([:a, :b, :c, :d] - hash.keys).empty?
```

or

```
hash.slice(:a, :b, :c, :d).size == 4
```

Answer (score 15):

Just in the spirit of TIMTOWTDI, here's another way. If you `require 'set'` (in the std lib) then you can do this:

```
Set[:a,:b,:c,:d].subset? hash.keys.to_set
```

Answer (score 9):

You can get a list of missing keys this way:

```
expected_keys = [:a, :b, :c, :d]
missing_keys = expected_keys - hash.keys
```

If you just want to see if there are any missing keys:

```
(expected_keys - hash.keys).empty?
```

Answer (score 8):

I like this way to solve this:

```
subset = [:a, :b, :c, :d]
subset & hash.keys == subset
```

It is fast and clear.

Comment: Works unless one needs a strict match.  [:a, :b, :c, :d] & [:a, :b, :c, :d, :e]
=> [:a, :b, :c, :d]

Comment: Yeah, however the question wasn't about that.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution:

([also given as answer at](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13786550/check-if-two-hashes-have-the-same-set-of-keys/51409600#51409600))

```
class Hash
    # doesn't check recursively
    def same_keys?(compare)
      return unless compare.class == Hash
        
      self.size == compare.size && self.keys.all? { |s| compare.key?(s) }
    end
end

a = c = {  a: nil,    b: "whatever1",  c: 1.14,     d: false  }
b     = {  a: "foo",  b: "whatever2",  c: 2.14,   "d": false  }
d     = {  a: "bar",  b: "whatever3",  c: 3.14,               }

puts a.same_keys?(b)                    # => true
puts a.same_keys?(c)                    # => true
puts a.same_keys?(d)                    # => false   
puts a.same_keys?(false).inspect        # => nil
puts a.same_keys?("jack").inspect       # => nil
puts a.same_keys?({}).inspect           # => false
```