# Find missing key in hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am stuck in a situation where I need to find missing key in the hash. But the problem is key is not certain it can be any key out of certain keys.

For example

```
 {"from"=>"abc@gmail.com", "to"=>"def@gmail.com:ijk@gmail.com:lmn@gmail.com", "subject"=>"hi", "body"=>"there", "cc" => "def@gmail.com:ijk@gmail.com", "bcc" => "def@gmail.com:ijk@gmail.com"}
```

Missing keys can be from, subject, to, body but not cc and bcc. So I need to find out which of the keys are missing in a hash in order to return the specific key to the user. I cannot do this at the model level
[This solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11552490/check-if-a-hashs-keys-include-all-of-a-set-of-keys) provided in this link is not helpful because it is just returning me true or false. Instead of that, I need the missing keys which are not present in my hash

Comment: You didn't read my question properly. The link which you have provided in that it will return me true or false only. It won't return me the specific key which is missing inside my hash

Comment: If `h` is your hash, is '['from', 'subject', 'to', 'body'] - h.keys` what you want?

Comment: @CarySwoveland - Sorry My bad I didn't check the 2nd example It is working thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make use of the [`Hash#keys`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Hash.html#method-i-keys) method

```
REQUIRED_KEYS = %w(from subject to body)
hash = {
  "from"=>"abc@gmail.com", 
  "to"=>"def@gmail.com:ijk@gmail.com:lmn@gmail.com", 
  "subject"=>"hi", 
  "body"=>"there", 
  "cc" => "def@gmail.com:ijk@gmail.com", 
  "bcc" => "def@gmail.com:ijk@gmail.com"
}

REQUIRED_KEYS - hash.keys
#=> []

hash.delete('to')
#=> "def@gmail.com:ijk@gmail.com:lmn@gmail.com"

REQUIRED_KEYS - hash.keys
#=> ["to"]
```