# How to fix keys in a jsonb field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, jsonb

I have a table with one jsonb field. I want that field to have onlye three keys, say the table schema is

name: string
dob: date
personal_data: jsonb

i want personal_data to have only three keys
personal_data: {
    mothers_name: '',
    father_name: '',
    random_key: ''

}

if i try to save some other key, it should show an error. I am using rails, any way to achieve this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this will handle two specific keys and any random 3rd key. If you want 3 specific keys only add the third key to the array and (self....).count == 3 instead of 2

*On yourmodel.rb*

before_save :check_personal_data

```
keys_to_always_match = [ :mothers_name, :father_name ]

def check_personal_data
  (self.personal_data.keys & keys_to_always_match).count == 2 && self.personal_data.count == 3 
end
```

You'll probably also want to add a default value to the migration:

```
t.jsonb :personal_data, default: { mothers_name: '', father_name: '', random_key: '' }
```

The elegant solution for the key matching comes from:

[Testing if a hash has any of a number of keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4743709/testing-if-a-hash-has-any-of-a-number-of-keys/4743729#4743729)

Comment: OK that's an options and as per my situation i also need to check if user is not trying to save any other key which is not mentions above

Comment: I'm gonna change to a sample with that, but from the information above you should be able to deduce a way of doing that, with .count == 3 && key1 && key2 && key3

Comment: @gurpreetsingh I've changed it to a much better solution